# Module resolution confusion in TypeScript with Angular 2

Tags: typescript

The line below raises a 404 error:

```
import * as reducers from './reducers';
```

The browser looks for the file: http://localhost:3000/app/reducers.js

It works when I add "/index" to the end of the path as in:

```
import * as reducers from './reducers/index';
```

I've seen some example apps that use the first method and work without problems, but I couldn't make it work for some reason.

Comment: You need to configure your module loader to map ./reducers to ./reducers/index.js. There are different ways to do that depending on your particular module loader.

Comment: So I guess the 'angular-quickstart' project is not configured as you told (https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

Comment: No it's not - I guess `reducers` is in the app folder? If so, there is nothing about `reducers` in [the app package config](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js#L32)

Comment: Yes, reducers folder is under the app folder. Thanks for the help.